# How to celebrate christmas with MS?

Tags: diet, multiple-sclerosis

One week ago, I knew I have multiple sclerosis. My right eye is affected and I can not see well. This question is about what should I eat to overcome MS.

I googled about beans and found controversy. I still don't know wither it is useful or harmful for me?

Also, Which one of these food is useful and which one is harmful? coriander -
latency -
Bee's honey -
Tahini - 
fried potatoes (fingers) - 
lentils - 
chickpeas - 
soybean - boiled liver of chicken - fried fish - boiled chicken without skin.

Christmas is coming and my family will celebrate by serving different types of food that contains fats, butter, meat, gateau and so on. 
Should I refuse to eat any of these? Or should I eat small amounts of meat and one piece of gateau? How do I know when I reach the maximum amount?

Comment: Are you receiving medication or will you be receiving any during Christmas?

Comment: I've taken 5 injections of solu-medrol and these days I take solupred and I'm not sure if my doctor will stop medication during christmas or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short:** Changes in diet have not been proven to help mitigate MS, but there are special diet recommendations for patients on glucocorticoid therapy (solu-medrol belongs to this group).

---

There have been hypotheses on various diets increasing the risk of MS, however, there is no strong scientific evidence that would confirm this. At best, the results from controlled studies were inconsistent.

There was a large prospective study on two cohorts of women (92,422 with 14 year follow-up and 95,389 with 4 years follow-up), which has shown:

> In these two large cohorts of women, we found no evidence that higher intake of saturated fat or lower intakes of polyunsaturated fat and fish omega-3 fatty acids were associated with an increased risk of MS. Intakes of dairy products, fish, red meats, poultry, and processed meats were also unrelated to risk of MS.
>
> Because of the prospective design, recall or selection biases are unlikely in this study, and the high follow-up rates minimize the concern that differential follow-up rates have effected our results. The estimates of total fat and specific types of fat derived from the dietary questionnaires used in this study reasonably reflect long-term intakes of study subjects
> (15–18). The fact that they have predicted risk of coronary heart disease in the NHS (31) further supports their validity.

**However**, many doctors do recommend a special diet when on glucocorticoid  therapy. Influence on electrolyte and sugar metabolism has been established with these medicines, as well as increased energy intake. The recommended diet is usually low in calories, fat and simple carbohydrates (no sugar I'm afraid or as little as possible), rich in protein; also low sodium and foods rich in potassium, calcium and vitamin D are recommended.

These nutritional strategies serve to prevent or mitigate potential metabolic side effects of corticosteroids. That being said, it is still a point of debate whether these are applied only in chronic systemic application of glucocorticoids or should they also be included in pulse therapy (short-term, high doses, the sort that you described).

Ultimately, the recommendations on diet should come from your doctor, and you should ask as many questions as you wish. Sometimes this sort of news comes as a bit of a shock, and it is good to have a family member with you and to write down the recommendations - when there is a lot to process it is easy to forget a crucial piece of information. Whatever you do, make sure to take your therapy as prescribed, as with corticosteroids, depending on how long you take them, it might be dangerous to abruptly stop - your doctor will know if this applies to your case.

---

Ref:

1. [Dietary Fat in Relation to Risk of Multiple Sclerosis among Two Large
   Cohorts of Women](http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/152/11/1056.full.pdf+html)
2. [Glucocorticoid Therapy and Cushing Syndrome Treatment & Management](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/921086-treatment#d8)
3. [Effects of glucocorticoids on energy metabolism and food intake in humans](http://ajpendo.physiology.org/content/271/2/E317.short)

Comment: On a personal note - I am very sorry that you had to receive such news, especially in this time of year. Still, there are several types of MS, most of them are not as severe as seen in the movies and one can lead a very normal life with some types. There are various sorts of disease-modifying therapy, which is taken regularly, even when you feel well, to improve your prognosis. The downside is that they are very expensive, but depending on the country you live in, insurance might cover it. All of this can be answered by your doctor, but while you are having problems with your vision [cont]

Comment: ... your doctor's primary concerns is probably to mitigate that as much as possible. But I urge you to ask about diet recommendations while on glucocorticoid therapy, it might seem like going through a lot of trouble in an inconvenient part of the year, but it can be well worth it in the long run. There are always low-fat, low sugar alternatives of holiday meals that are still  delicious.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much for your useful answer. It really helps.  I appreciate that you care about me personally. You're a wonderful. You make me worry-free. Merry Christmas and God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two substances in the diet being scientifically debated on.

- Gluten:

[Thomsen et al.](https://www.msard-journal.com/article/S2211-0348(18)30387-0/fulltext), The role of gluten in multiple sclerosis: A systematic review ("... literature search was conducted...")

- Cholesterol:

[Zhornitsky et al.](https://www.msard-journal.com/article/S2211-0348(15)30012-2/fulltext), Cholesterol  and markers of cholesterol turnover in multiple sclerosis: relationship with disease outcomes (review of several articles)

Also to be found is research on
Metabolic syndrome (abbreviations are: MS and MetS).

`Berrios Morales et al.`, 2014,  Metabolic Syndrome and Disability in Multiple Sclerosis: A Retrospective Study (...)

Thus,  any debate on diet concerning MetS might be relevant, and cholesterol seems a common denominator. However, "(l)imited data on the risk factors of metabolic syndrome (MetS) is currently available." Conversely, there seems to be no connection, at all,  between diabetes (related to MetS) and gluten.